# Load archived value from NSUserDefaults if it doesn't exist by overriding getter

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm trying to add a fallback function to load an archived copy of a class if the property isn't set.

I've got the setter working fine so that it stores the value (and all of the NSCoding is working as expected), but if I try to reference this anywhere else, instead of using the actual variable property, it's always loading from NSUserDefaults.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
public var currentUser: User? {
    get {
        var user = self.currentUser
        // ^ this totally blows it up
        if (user == nil) {
            user = User.init(name: "") as? User
            if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("currentUser") as? NSData {
                let unarc = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data)
                user = unarc.decodeObjectForKey("root") as? User
            }
        }
        return user
    }
    set(value) {
        self.currentUser = value
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(value!), forKey: "currentUser")
    }
}
```

Comment: you need show the User class declaration

Comment: Why exactly? It's got a couple of basic properties and an init method. I can add it, but I'm on mobile now and don't have access.

Comment: Because it needs to be NSCoding compliant and you need to save it as NSData

Comment: They are. The NSCoding works fine. The problem is that when overriding the getter here, it ALWAYS pulls from NSUserDefaults instead of returning the currentUser instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening with your code, is calling `self.currentUser` inside `self.currentUser`'s getter. When you specify a custom getter for a computed property, you don't actually have storage for that instance, i.e. the value isn't saved, rather always computed.
What you need is another instance property, which can be private, say `_currentUser` where you actually save the value, and which you check in you custom getter.

```
private var _currentUser: User?
public var currentUser: User? {
    get {
        if (_currentUser == nil) {
            _currentUser = User.init(name: "") as? User
            if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("currentUser") as? NSData {
                let unarc = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: data)
                _currentUser = unarc.decodeObjectForKey("root") as? User
            }
        }
        return _currentUser
    }
    set(value) {
        _currentUser = value
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(value!), forKey: "currentUser")
    }
}
```